# Continuous function on topology with cartesian product

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $(Y_i,\tau_i),i=1,\dots,n$ be topological spaces and $Y=Y_1 \times \dots \times Y_n$ be the cartesian product. Let $(X,\tau$) be a topological space and consider $$f_1:X \rightarrow Y_1, \cdots,f_n:X \rightarrow Y_n.$$

Show that the function $f:(X,\tau)\rightarrow (Y,\tau_0)$ definided by $f=(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ is continuous if and only if each coordinate is continuous.

I have managed to prove the first part, but i'm stucked with the continuous coordinates. I know that each $f_i(x)$ is in a neighborhood, but i don't know how i can prove that $$x \in X\cap V \Longrightarrow (f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x)) \in W$$

with $V$ and $W$ being the neighborhoods of the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Prove the contrapositive: if one of the coordinate functions is not continuous, then $f$ is not continuous.

Suppose that $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and $f_k$ is not continuous. Then there is a $U\in\tau_k$ such that $f_k^{-1}[U]$ is not open in $X$. Let $V=\{\langle y_1,\ldots,y_n\rangle\in Y:y_k\in U\}$; then $V$ is open in $Y$, and

$$\begin{align*}
f^{-1}[V]&=\{x\in X:f(x)\in V\}\\
&=\{x\in X:f_k(x)\in U\}\\
&=f_k^{-1}[U]
\end{align*}$$

is not open in $X$, so $f$ is not continuous.